# InnerHtml dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I query data from database and show in `InnerHtml` like
[image: Screnshot]

I want to add `checkbox` in `innerHtml` like I created in the Red color `checkbox` in the image which is not the part of result. How can I add a `checkbox` in `InnerHtml` like red one?

```
WebBrowserDocument +=
                                "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">" +
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<td width=\"5\" bgcolor=\"#" + ContentTone + "\"></td>" +
                                "<td width=\"8\"></td>" +
                                "<td>" +
                                    " <table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" width=\"700\"> " +
                                    " <tr> " +
                                    " <td class=\"MainHeadline\"><a href=\"|play|" + urlString + "\"> " +
                                    " " + makeBold(dr["issues"].ToString()) + " " +
                                    " </a>" +
                                    " <span class=\"MainHeadlinePart\">" + makeBold(dr["ProvinceName"].ToString()) + " - " + makeBold(dr["CityName"].ToString()) + " - " + makeBold(dr["AreaName"].ToString()) + "</span>" +
                                    "</td> " +
                                    " </tr> " +
                                    " <tr> " +
                                    " <td class=\"line2\"> " +
                                    " " + dr["channelName"].ToString() + "  " + dr["transmissionDate"].ToString() + " " + dr["startTime"].ToString() +
                                    " </td> " +
                                    " </tr> " +
                                    " <tr> " +
                                    " <td class=\"programName\"> " +
                                    " " + makeBold(dr["programName"].ToString()) + " - " + dr["programTypeName"].ToString() + " (" + dr["contentType"].ToString() + ") " +
                                    " </td> " +
                                    " </tr> " +
                                    " <tr> " +
                                    " <td class=\"descriptions\"> " +
                                    " " + makeBold(dr["KeyWords"].ToString()) + "</td> " +
                                    " </tr> " +
                                    " <tr> " +
                                    " <td class=\"persons\"> " +
                                    " " + makeBold(dr["personsName"].ToString()) + " " +
                                    " </td> " +
                                    " </tr> " +
                                    " <tr> " +
                                    " <td class=\"persons\"> " +
                                    " " + makeBold(dr["PartiesName"].ToString()) + " " +
                                    " </td> " +
                                    " </tr> " +
                                    " <tr> " +
                    //" <td class=\"descriptions\"> " +
                    //" <a href=\"|update|" + urlString + "\">Update</a> | <a href=\"|delete|" + urlString + "\">Delete</a> | <a href=\"|save|" + urlString + "\">Save To Hard Drive</a> | <a href=\"|saveAsWMV|" + urlString + "\">Save As WMV</a>" +
                    //" </td> " +
                                    " <td class=\"descriptions\"> " +
                                    " <a href=\"|download|" + urlString + "\">Download</a>" +
                                " </td> " +
                                " </tr> " +
                                " </table> " +
                            " </td> " +
                            " </tr> " +
                            " </table> " +
                                " <br /> ";
```

You can see Download tag in last line of code.
I want checkbox along with Download tag.

Comment: Where are you getting the result HTML from? DO you know the structure of that?

Comment: result is getting from database

Comment: add it in your repeater template

Comment: Result is shown by web browser document. can I Add checkbox inside web browser documnet in code behind page???

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates the document?

Comment: @Mohsinjan110 you have to post html code , so we can help to u to add the checkbox

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript or jquery, you'll have to parse the html before you assign it to the web document and insert the checkbox code.

Comment: @Mohsinjan110 check edit below , do u want to add the checkbox after page render ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after `" <a href=\"|download|" + urlString + "\">Download</a>" +` add your checkbox , it should be like this :

```
" <a href=\"|download|" + urlString + "\">Download</a>" +

"<input type='checkbox' name='chkbox' value='chkbox'>"
```

Comment: Change to double quotes around attribute values for valid markup, imo.